# Font awesome in IE7

Tags: font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome for my webapp and all works well except for IE7.  Unfortunately I have to support IE7 :(

What makes matters worse is that it is somewhat of a legacy app that I inherited and the customer does not want the icons/glyphs to change that came with bootstrap.  Yes there a some Font Awesome icons that are just slightly different than the bootstrap glyps.  Go figure customer noticed.

I am no expert by any means so this is what I did (and I think it 'should' work):

I took the css from Font Awesome and changes all css with 'icon-' to 'fa-icon-'.  This means that in my app I did not change from using the glyphs that came with bootstrap as those classes are all 'icon-'.  And all Font Awesome icons in my app are of class 'fa-icon-'.

My problem is that I must have messed something up as far as IE7 compatibility.  I am including font-awesome-ie7.min.css in my header correctly when the browser is IE7, double checked that.

Problem is that when I go to IE7 I don't see the icons at all.

Here are some snippets of my modified css.  Any and all ideas welcome ;)

font-awesome-ie7.min.css

```
[class^="fa-icon"],[class*=" fa-icon"]{font-family: FontAwesome;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;}
.btn.dropdown-toggle [class^="fa-icon"], .btn.dropdown-toggle [class*=" fa-icon"]{line-height: 1.4em;}
.fa-icon-large{font-size: 1.3333em;}
.ie7icon(@inner){*zoom: ~"expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '@{inner}&nbsp;')";}

.fa-icon-glass                { .ie7icon('&#xf000;'); }
.fa-icon-music                { .ie7icon('&#xf001;'); }
.fa-icon-search               { .ie7icon('&#xf002;'); }
.fa-icon-envelope             { .ie7icon('&#xf003;'); }
```

font-awesome.min.css

```
@font-face{font-family: 'FontAwesome';src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
[class^="fa-icon-"]:before,[class*=" fa-icon-"]:before {font-family: FontAwesome;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;display: inline-block;text-decoration: inherit;}
a[class^="fa-icon-"],a[class*=" fa-icon-"]{display: inline-block;text-decoration: inherit;}
.fa-icon-large:before{vertical-align: middle;font-size: 4/3em;}
.btn,.nav-tabs{[class^="fa-icon-"],[class*=" fa-icon-"]{line-height: .9em;}}
li{[class^="fa-icon-"],[class*=" fa-icon-"]{display: inline-block;width: 1.25em;text-align: center;}.fa-icon-large:before,.fa-icon-large:before {width: 1.5*1.25em;}}
ul.icons{list-style-type: none;margin-left: 2em;text-indent: -.8em;li {[class^="fa-icon-"],[class*=" fa-icon-"] {width: .8em;}.fa-icon-large:before,.fa-icon-large:before {vertical-align: initial;}}}

.fa-icon-glass:before                { content: "\f000"; }
.fa-icon-music:before                { content: "\f001"; }
.fa-icon-search:before               { content: "\f002"; }
.fa-icon-envelope:before             { content: "\f003"; }
.fa-icon-heart:before                { content: "\f004"; }
.fa-icon-star:before                 { content: "\f005"; }
```

Comment: Very nice, I did the same thing, without using less. Could you please give your site URL to see your final CSS ? I have to support IE7 too... What a such pain !

Comment: Sorry not up on a public URL.

Comment: No problem, I finally got this ! thanks for your post by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my rookie mistake was with not compiling the ie less file.  Once I compiled font-awesome-ie7.less into a css file and then included that things worked great.